# How to define a model one-to-many relationship using a foreign key

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I am trying to connect to tables using a foreign key in the following code:

models.py

```
class DailyTestDraft(models.Model):
    index = models.AutoField(db_column='Index', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    gantry = models.IntegerField(db_column='Gantry', null=True)
    '.....'

class DailyTestInput(models.Model):
    index = models.AutoField(db_column='Index', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    energyID = models.IntegerField(db_column='energyID',null=True)
    '.......'
    indexid = models.ForeignKey(DailyTestDraft, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,    default=None)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

views.py:

```
form = DailyTestDraft(gantry=3)
form.save()
form2 = DailyTestInput(indexid=form)
form2.save()
```

I would like the table `DailyTestInput` to save the primary key of `DailyTestDraft` (which is index) into its foreign key variable which is `indexid`.

However, I get the error:

> "(1054, "Unknown column 'indexid_id' in 'field list'")"

and when I change it to

```
form2 = DailyTestInput(indexid_id=form)
```

I get the error:

> "Field 'index' expected a number but got <DailyTestDraft: 58>."

But when I change it to

```
form2 = DailyTestInput(indexid_id=form.index)
```

then I get the same error 1054.

If I put

```
form2 = DailyTestInput(indexid=form.index)
```

then I get the error:

> "Cannot assign "58": "DailyTestInput.indexid" must be a "DailyTestDraft" instance."

Sorry for all the options, but I've been trying to make it work in many ways and I am a bit lost as to how it should be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Your database column name differs from Django's [Database Representation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#database-representation):

> Behind the scenes, Django appends `"_id"` to the field name to create its database column name.

You can change this by specifying `db_column`:

```py
indexid = models.ForeignKey(..., db_column='indexid')
```